# How to merge two styled-components which are in different base components but have similar styles?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to merge these two styled-components into one.

```
const CustomInput = styled.input`
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%; 
`;
const CustomTextarea = styled.textarea`
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%; 
`;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
const sharedCSS = css`
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%; 
`
const CustomInput = styled.Input`
  ${sharedCSS}
`
const CustomTextarea = styled.textarea`
  ${sharedCSS}
`
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Akrion. :D